# Python weird string processing issue with strip

Tags: python, string, strip

Can anyone explain the following behavior to me?  This doesn't make any sense.

I have a string:

```
In [170]: t = "c:\\website\\site-env\\scripts"
```

I try to strip "c:\website" from the front, and it doesn't work:

```
In [171]: t.strip("c:\\website")
Out[171]: '-env\\scrip'
```

I back up a little to see where it breaks:

```
In [172]: t.strip("c:\\websi")
Out[172]: 'te\\site-env\\script'
```

For some reason, it happens after the "t"!

```
In [173]: t.strip("c:\\websit")
Out[173]: '-env\\scrip'
```

Any ideas?  I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you actually... read the docs? You can do a `help("".strip)` in a Python shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`strip` uses the *characters*, not the string. For example, `"abcdefg".strip("facedb")` would result in `"g"`. Use a slice instead:

```
t[len(r'c:\website'):] if t.startswith(r'c:\website') else t
```

Comment: Doh!  Should've read the docs a little more closely.  Thanks.

Comment: t = t.replace(r'c:\website', '', 1) is imho simpler

Comment: With the third arg `1`, it will only replace the first occurrence from left-to-right. In this case, that's sufficient. In principle you're correct though; The two solutions are logically distinct.